# read content from text field in another class

Tags: java, class, lucene, textfield

I have two classes, one class is a GUI which asks the user to select 2 file directories and displays the directories in the two text fields "input Line" and "input Line 1" respectively text field.
the second class is supposed to read these two directories and perform an indexing operation.
My problem is I do not know how to get the second class to read the directory(path) in the text field from the first class into the "index path" and "doc path"
I have tried importing the first class but it still didn't work
it gives me a n error message saying "input Line cannot be resolved to a variable. these are the classes and their codes:
first class snippet:

```
openButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public  void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
          JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
          chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
          int option = chooser.showOpenDialog(uploaad.this);
          if (option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
              File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
              inputLine.setText(file.getAbsolutePath());

          }
          else {
            statusbar.setText("You canceled.");
          }
        }
      });


    indexButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ap) {
            JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
              chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
              int option = chooser.showOpenDialog(uploaad.this);
              if (option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                  File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
                  inputLine1.setText(file.getAbsolutePath());

              }
              else {
                statusbar.setText("You canceled.");
              }
            }
          });
```

second class snippet:

```
 String indexPath = inputLine.getText;
    String docsPath = inputLine1;
    boolean create = true;
    for(int i=0;i<args.length;i++) {
     if ("-index".equals(args[i])) {
    indexPath = args[i+1];
    i++;
    } else if ("-docs".equals(args[i])) {
    docsPath = args[i+1];
    i++;
    } else if ("-update".equals(args[i])) {
      create = false;
     }
   }

   if (docsPath == null) {
   System.err.println("Usage: " + usage);
   System.exit(1);
    }

  final Path docDir = Paths.get(docsPath);
  if (!Files.isReadable(docDir)) {
  System.out.println("Document directory '" +docDir.toAbsolutePath()+ "'  
  does not exist or is not readable, please check the path");           
  System.exit(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are separate class, then you have to have objects of those classes.

if one field is on a class, you have to access it via your objects. If you intend to access fields of a class, define the field as static.

```
public class MyClass {
   int a;
   static int b;
}
```

then to access a:

```
MyClass first = new MyClass();
first.a ///
```

to access b:

```
you just need to use MyClass.b
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that the text box variables are private. If that is the case, then you would not go very far with the other class.